# use list.push_back() inside loop, get around invalidate iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list

- I want to use the function `.push_back()` inside the loop without mess up iterators and get involved in an infinite loop. If some conditions on existing items of the list are verified create a new object and append it at the end of the list.

  How ?
- I noticed that when I use `push_front()` instead of `push_back()` I have no issue. Why ?
- does `push_back()` affect the vlaue of `.end()` and `push_front()` that of `.begin()` ?

**Notes:**

- I cant use a loop based on `list.size()` I need access to objects for tests.
- Since I am using double nested loop I think for loop is more suitable than while in this case.
- I dont need to check (reach) newly added items at the end of the list.

  ```
   void fct(list<myclass *>& lst) {
   list<myclass *>::iterator it1,it2;
   for ( it=lst.begin();it1 != lst.end();it1++) {
       if (condition on *it1) {
           for ( it2=lst.begin();it2 != lst.end();it2++) {
               if (condition on *it2) {
                  myclass *newobj = new myclass();
                  lst.push_back(newobj);
                  //infinite loop here in second loop
               }
           }
       }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: That's impossible to answer, since we have no idea what your code is *intended* to do.

Comment: if some conditions are verified create a new object and append it at the end of the list

Comment: Do you need to process the newly added objects? If not, add them to a new list and splice them in afterwards.

Comment: just edit code add more details

Comment: T.C i only test conditions on objects

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Which elements are the loops *intended* to loop over? Just the elements inside `lst` before the loop starts? Or also the objects you added to it during the loop?

Comment: inline `list<myclass *> lst (10);`,  `for (it= lst.begin();it != lst.end();it++)
        *it = new myclass();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ( it2=lst.begin();it2 != lst.end();it2++) {
    //test on *it2
    myclass *newobj = new myclass();
    lst.push_back(newobj);
    //infinite loop here in second loop
}
```

It's an infinite loop because the "next" link from the node `it2` is tracking will be connected to the new node, then the iterator's moved to the just-inserted node and you do it again, and again.....  You could instead increment `it2` *before* doing the `push_back`, then record the equality with `end()`, *after* the `push_back` if there was equality, `break` from the loop.  Remember to remove the `++it2` from the `for` statement or you'll be processing alternating elements (and potentially trying to go past `end()` with *undefined behaviour*).

You can use the same insights to work out whether you need to do something for the outer loop.

Comment: if i inc it2 before push_back() the code from push_back() to the end of condition bloc will miss the first item returned by .begin()

Comment: @Cfun: you can decrement it again if you like (and re-increment it in the `for` statement as you've been doing), or take a reference/pointer/iterator to `*it2` before incrementing.  Yet another approach is to record the `list`'s `size()` before you start `push_back`-ing, increment each time through the loop, and terminate the loop when you've counted the initial number of elements.  T.C.'s suggestion to push new elements on a separate container and append them all afterwards is also fine.

Comment: i think it will be nice to break upon count reach size(), but how to gurantee what size() we are using the old or the new one?

Comment: Each time `size()` is called it will be the size of the `list` at that moment, but you want to break on the pre-`push_back` size, so record that before entering your loop:  `size_t initial_size = lst.size(); for (it2 = lst.begin(); initial_size--; ++it2) ...`.  (`initial_size--` will count down and execute the loop initial_size-times).